# Invalid column name 'id' - this is my error while i am trying to select specific columns from my table

Tags: sql-server, select, try-catch

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'id'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError

Code :

```
try
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\SVB_db.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = null;
    string sq = "SELECT event_name, user-id, time_in, time_out, event_date, venue_name FROM Event";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sq, con);

    SqlDataReader r1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (r1.HasRows)
    {
        while (r1.Read())
        {
            if (r1.GetValue(0).ToString().Equals(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value))
            {
                txtEventName.Text = r1.GetValue(0).ToString();
                txtUsrID.Text = r1.GetValue(1).ToString();
                txtTmeIn.Text = r1.GetValue(2).ToString();
                txtTimeOut.Text = r1.GetValue(3).ToString();
                txtEventDate.Text = r1.GetValue(4).ToString();
                DropDownList1.Text = r1.GetValue(5).ToString();
            }
        }

        r1.Close();
    }

    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex);
}
```

Comment: Questions on SO are supposed to be a bit more than a "write a one word sentence in the title, then dump all your code in the body and hit submit"

Answer (score 1):

**user-id** is looking kinda suspicious. Maybe it should be

`..., user_id, time_in...`

If user-id is correct, than you should try

`...[user-id], time_in ...`

Comment: Exactly - the minus sign violates the rules for [regular identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15)